# item get is not a function vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

```
methods: {
  fechData: function () {
    console.log("i am in fech function ...................")
    var course4_table = this.$parse.Object.extend(this.course);
    const query = new this.$parse.Query(course4_table);
    const results = query.find().then(res => {
      const arrayLength = res.length;
      for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        const item = res[i];
        const index = item.get("index");
        const text = item.get("text");
        const audio = item.get("audio");
        this.course_results.push({ "index": index, "text": text, "audio": audio });
      }
      console.log(this.course_results);
    });
  },
}
```

when i use push inside for loop give this error "item get is not a function "
but when i clear this line

```
this.course_results.push({"index": index, "text": text, "audio": audio});
```

how i can resolve this ?

i can use this outside for loop 
and The problem will be resolved

```
this.course_results=res;
```

but i want Edit first res
tnx

Comment: what does console.log(item) look like?

Comment: It works properly and pushes all values .The problem is that while doing it right, but page is not loaded and give me error

Comment: Are you sure it pushes ALL values? Does this.course_results.length ===  res.length?

Comment: yes i check it now

Comment: can you create a demo on codepen with test data?

Answer (score 0):

```
data() {
  return {
    course_results: []
  }
},
```

Please check if you defined the component data correctly.